# Understanding Ziv's proof of zero sum problem .

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, additive-combinatorics

I was going through [the proof of zero sum problem in one dimension as provided by Abraham Ziv](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1961-25.pdf). The problem statement is to prove that given a set of $2n+1$ integers, we can find at least $n$ integers whose sum is divisible by $n$. The author first proved for the cases where $n$ is prime.

He chooses $\ s $ integers which are coprime to $p$, such that for no two $\ i , \ j \ \in \ N $ , $(\ a_i -\ a_j \ ) \equiv \ mod \ p $.

He starts up by proving in a set $\ A $, where any $x \in A$ is of the form  $\sum_{i=1}^s \ c_i \ a_i$, where $\ c_i$ is either 1 or 0. The number of congruence classes modulo $\ p $ in $A$ are at least  $\ s  + 1$ congruent classes .

The proof is by induction. Now when he is trying to prove for $\ s  +1$, he assumes there are minimum $ k $ congruent classes, $b_1 , b_2 , ... b_k $. By a particular congruence class modulo $\ p $ , I understand to be the set of numbers which leave the a same particular remainder when divided by $\ p $.  What exactly are the integers $b_1, b_2, ... b_k $ here? Are they the remainders that are obtained after dividing by $\ p $?

Given the lack of clarity about these numbers, I am also confused by what he means when he says that "at least one of the integers $\ b_i + \ a_s $ is not congruent to all the $b $ 's." How can he ascertain this?

I hope someone can explain this to me.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you read the original paper? There are write ups that are easier to follows.

Comment: What do you mean by $(\ a_i -\ a_j \ ) \equiv \ mod \ p $? Did you want to write $a_i-a_j \equiv 0 \pmod p$ `$a_i-a_j \equiv 0 \pmod p$`?

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly are the integers $b_1, b_2, ... b_k $ here?

You can think of  them as one representative of the class.

> Are they the remainders that are obtained after dividing by $\ p $?

If you want you can take it to be the remainder.

> Given the lack of clarity about these numbers, I am also confused by what he means when he says that "at least one of the integers $\ b_i + \ a_s $ is not congruent to all the $b $ 's." How can he ascertain this?

Suppose that $b_i + a_s $ equals some $b_j$ for all $i$.

This would yield that you have $b_1 + j a_s$ for $j=0,\dots, s$ in the set of residue classes formed by the $b_i$.  Yet these are all distinct modulo $p$ so this is impossible, as there are $s+1$.

If you know the Cauchy—Davenport theorem you can use that instead.